# Generate Hash fron an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, lazy-evaluation, memoization

In my `React` app, I am currently thinking of ways to optimise performance. Having read about `lazy evaluation`, I wonder whether its possible to generate a unique hash code based on the current content of the obj.

The purpose is to compare the hashes to find out whether any prop within the obj has changed. Memorization.

Is this possible?

Update after Roman's comment:
To clarify, I was wondering whether there already exists such a library. To further elaborate on your excellent points, in my case, for the generation of hash, it would be only values (& not the keys) used to generate the seq. Also, all the values will either be string or converted to string, funcs can be ignored. Thanks for food for thought, I am considering taking a stab at writing such a very specific case tiny library...

Answer (score 1):

There is no hashing in Javascript directly available, and there probably will never be. The issue with it is in the definition of object equality. Two objects consider equal should result in the same hash, isn't it? But how do you know if two objects are equal? If you only use the === to compare two objects, then you are comparing the pointers but not the contents, and in that case you don't need a hash. So, the equality should involve the content of the object, like if a = {b: 0, c: 1} and b = {b: 0, c: 1}, then they are equal. But, what happens if the property values are not numbers, but other objects or functions? Will you just compare that the properties are pointing to the same object or compare recursively? And what about functions?

So, if you want to implement a hash, you will need to take several decisions about what object equality means first.

Comment: To clarify, I was wondering whether there already exists such a library. To further elaborate on your excellent points, in my case, for the generation of hash, it would be only values (& not the keys) used to generate the seq. Also, all the values will either be `string` or converted to string, funcs can be ignored. Thanks for food for thought, I am considering taking a stab at writing such a very specific case tiny library...

Answer (score 1):

The [object-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash) library does this. With `{respectType: true}` (the default), it covers pretty much every edge case. For example, to hash `{ foo: 'bar', bob: (x) => x * 2 }` it looks at

```
'object:5:string:9:prototype:Undefined,string:9:__proto__:object
:3:string:9:prototype:Undefined,
string:9:__proto__:Null,string:11:constructor:fn:string:8:[native]string
:20:function-name:Objectobject:0:,,
string:11:constructor:fn:string
:8:[native]string:20:function-name:Objectstring:12:[CIRCULAR:2],
string:3:bob:fn:string:12:(x) => x * 2string
:17:function-name:bobobject:3:string:9:prototype:Undefined,
string:9:__proto__:fn:string:8:[native]string
:14:function-name:object:0:,string:11:constructor:fn:string:8:
[native]string:22:function-name:Functionobject:0:,,string:3:foo:string:3:bar,'
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the key advantages of React is that you don't need to build your own diffing algorithm. See [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) for a description of some technical details of React's approach.

Comment: Thank you Yosef, however, there are plenty of scenarios where you may want to stop React from running this its own diff algo when there is no need for it. Think of this step as preceding React's own logic. This is similar in intent to how Redux handles state updated to 'smart' components. Hope that clarifies.